# Firestore/Firebase - Approach to model data for followed/following user post

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I have an application based on firestore. The app's users can subscribe to other users's accounts. A user may have too many followers and too many posts. In a view, I want to query the posts of the users that follow a certain user. Right now, each post has a field 'creatorId'. An easy way to achieve that can be a query that has an OR clause, but firestore does not support that. I have two approaches:

1. Create one query per user followed, then merge each result into a single promise. Problems: The view should show the posts paginated, in this approach can't determinate it. In addition, one user can follow many users, so many queries should be made for then merge these results.
2. Add to each post a map like this:

```json
    followers: {
        follower1: true,
        follower3:true,
        followerX:true
        ...
    }
```

And do a query like this: where("followers." + user.id, "==", true). Problems: If a user has thousands and thousands of followers, the followers field would be very very big.

My questions is: Is there anther approach to model it? You have to keep in mind that que view should be paginate and the query should be optimal.

Answer (score 0):

You can model it using three collections.

**Users** : Basic user data with aggregated follow counts.

```
users/{userID}
  -- userInfo (any)
  -- followerCount (number)
  -- followedCount (number)
```

**Relationships** : Stores relationships between users.

```
relationships/{followerID_followedID}
  -- followerId (string)
  -- followedId (string)
  -- createdAt  (timestamp)
```

**Posts** : Stores posts created by a user.

```
posts/{post_ID}
      -- userId (string)
      -- post_info (map)
      -- createdAt  (timestamp)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: How does this work if we need to pull posts from all followed users for a given user?